# Customizing Express 4.x automagic OPTIONS response

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Express 4.x, and I'm trying to customize the automatically generated OPTIONS response, without having to re-implement all of the functionality that express is already providing for free.

So, for example, if I have PUT and POST handlers registered on `/foo`, making an OPTIONS call to `/foo` will return an `Allow` header with `PUT,POST`, and a body with the same value. What I am trying to do is to just customize this response. So where express normally returns a body with

```
PUT,POST
```

I would like to return something like

```
{"methods":["PUT","POST"]}
```

Is there any way to do this without fully re-implementing everything express is doing behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to handle options explicitly on each route, and pull the allowed methods from `req.route.methods`.

```
app
    .route('/foo')
    .post(...)
    .put(...)
    .options(funtion(req, res, next){
        var allowMethods = req.route.methods;
    });
```